# Static members of nullable types

Tags: c#, nullable, static-members

In c# a value-type cannot have a value of `null`, however you can enable this by appending a question mark.

e.g.

```
int intCannotBeNull = 1;
int? intCanBeNull = null;
```

Additionally, in C# many value types have `static` members so you can do this for example:

```
string strValue = "123";
intCannotBeNull = int.Parse(strValue);
```

However you can't do either of these:

```
intCanBeNull = int?.Parse(strValue);
intCanBeNull = (int?).Parse(strValue);
```

C# gets confused. Is there a valid syntax that means `strValue` could be `null` or a valid integer value and have the assignment work?

I know there are easy workarounds, for example:

```
intCanBeNull = (strValue == null) ? null : (int?)int.Parse(strValue);
```

and other variants of the same thing but that's just messy...

Comment: I think it's not C# that's confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<int>`. You are asking about `Nullable<int>.Parse`. There is no such method. That is where your confusion lies.

Comment: I actually hadn't realised you could do Nullable<int> in C#, though now I think about it, it makes perfect sense since in VB.Net you can do Nullable(of Integer) (I think, it's been a while since I did VB!)

It's a shame that Nullable<int>.Parse doesn't exist.

Comment: @DJL: It is impossible to exist, since it is a method of `int`, not `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: Nullable<T> Parse(string Val)
{
  if (Val==null)
  { 
    return null;
  } else {
     return GetType(int).GetMethod("Parse").Invoke(null, Val);
  }
}

or something along those lines...

Answer (score 1):

`Parse` will not handle `null` values, It will throw exception. You have to use either [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to parse

```
Convert.ToInt32(int or int?)
```

This applies for long, float, decimal etc..

Answer (score 1):

`int?` is in fact `Nullable<int>`. That [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) struct doesn't have the methods of the `T` class. Hence, you have to do it yourself.

In the case of `int?`, you could try something like this:

```
string s = "1";

int? result;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
{
    result = null;
}
else
{
    int o; // just a temp variable for the `TryParse` call
    if (int.TryParse(s, out o))
    {
        result = o;
    }
    else
    {
        result = null;
    }
}

// use result
```